# cambiar valores exactos con mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

tengo un pequeño problema con findByIdAndUpdate en mongoose:

mi codigo:

```
const editCarrito = await Carrito.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {pedido:{ cantidad: cantidad, bebidas:bebidas.toString(), rentrega: rentrega}, comentarios:{vegetariano: vegetariano.toString(),retirar: retirar, adicional: adicional}})
```

el problema:

tengo estos datos guardados en mongoDB:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al guardar editcarrito borra datos importantes como tipo, nombre, platoid.
necesito que esos datos queden allí y por eso no los incluyo en pedido pensando que al no estar no modificara nada como pasa con image o userid:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna idea?
gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const editCarrito = await Carrito.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: { 'pedido.cantidad': cantidad, 'pedido.bebidas':bebidas.toString(), 'pedido.rentrega': rentrega}})
```

la propiedad `$set` es la clave